# C Program linking Error?

Tags: c, visual-c++, linker, linker-errors

I have a situation. I have some functions in a header file that are declared with extern keyword. I have their definition in a C file. these two files are in the same directory. I made a visual studio project and include the header file. when I use the functions declared in header file. the program gives me linking error (LNK2019). I inserted the path of the directory containing the header and C file in include additional directories. but the problem is still there. How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you included the file to your solution?

Comment: which file, Header or C? Should I include them in project of should copy them in project directory?

Comment: try including the header file in the solution

Comment: When it shows a linking error, it means you are successful in compiling. So, it may not be the business of path setting, but -- have you add your C file in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all of you. I found the problem but above answers are also very helpful. the problem was that I was calling those functions which definition was in `.c` file. But I was calling it in my `.cpp` file. This was the reason for this error. I changed the extension of .cpp file to .c file and now it is working fine. Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

Functions don't need to be declared with the extern keyword. It is redundant.

Your error message is telling you that one of the functions you define (not just declare) is referencing an extern variable, but that the source file that declares that variable (i.e., where it is declared without the extern keyword) is not being linked.

Comment: functions in the source file do not use any variables except the local ones. I tried by commenting the whole function code. but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the C source file which contain the function definition into the visual studio project file? I believe that the linker is complaining that it cannot find the function definitions

Comment: I think you're right. And exactly, who complains 'cannot find definitions' is the linker but not the compiler. The compiler likely complains problems in 'declaration'.

Comment: haha, yes you are right that it is the linker who is complaining. I should have made it clearer. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is to add the `.c` file to the project/solution. That's the purpose of the project: to refer to all necessary implementation files (i.e. `.c` files). Apparently, you didn't do that. Hence the error.

You don't need to add *header* files (i.e. `.h` files) to the project/solution. Header files are usually added to the project for pure convenience, so that you can see them listed in one place. Otherwise, it is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `xx.h` (which you're including in `prog.c`) and `xx.c` are in `C:\dev\c\libx`:

```
cl /I C:\dev\c\libx prog.c                C:\dev\c\libx\xx.c
cl /I C:\dev\c\libx prog.c /link /LIBPATH:C:\dev\c\libx xx.obj
```

Same story if you have a `LIB` instead of an `OBJ`.

In Visual Studio, as others have said, just add the source file to your project. Right click on your project in the project explorer, "Add ...", "Existing element ..." (or similar in English), then browse to the file.